# TensorflowJS model fails to learn

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I built a TensorflowJS model that learns how to play a snake game that I made. I've followed everything I found online, but I can get my model to improve even after hundreds of games.

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
async function main(currentTime) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(main)
  aIModelChoice(snakeBody, applePosition)
  updateGameState()
  draw(gameBoard)
  checkIfLost()
  if (gameOver) {
    await updateAIModel(snakeBody, applePosition, -1, gameOver);
    console.log("UPDATING MODEL WITH REWARD -1")
  } else if (appleEaten){
    await updateAIModel(snakeBody, applePosition, +1, gameOver);
    console.log("UPDATING MODEL WITH REWARD +1")
  } else {
    await updateAIModel(snakeBody, applePosition, -0.1, gameOver);
    console.log("UPDATING MODEL WITH REWARD 0")
  }
  appleEaten = false
  if (gameOver) {
      reset()
  }
}
```

```
export function initiateAIModel() {
  window.model = tf.sequential();
  window.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 64, inputShape: [100], activation: "relu" }));
  window.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 32, activation: "relu" }));
  window.model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, activation: "softmax" }));
  window.model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
    metrics: ["accuracy"]
  });
  window.gamma = 0.9;
  window.epsilon = 1.0;
  let done = false;
  console.log("Model initiated");
}

function getState(snakeBody, applePosition) {
  const state = [];
  let xValues = [];
  let yValues = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < snakeBody.length; i++) {
    xValues.push(snakeBody[i].x);
    yValues.push(snakeBody[i].y);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < window.gridsize; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < window.gridsize; j++) {
      if (xValues.includes(j) && yValues.includes(i)) {
        state.push(1);
      } else if (applePosition.x === j && applePosition.y === i) {
        state.push(2);
      } else {
        state.push(0);
      }
    }
  }
  return state;
}

export function aIModelChoice(snakeBody, applePosition) {
  window.state = getState(snakeBody, applePosition);
  let selectedAction
  if (Math.random() < window.epsilon) {
    // Choose a random action
    selectedAction = ["UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", "RIGHT"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  } else {
    // Choose the action with the highest predicted reward
    const actionProbs = window.model.predict(tf.tensor2d([window.state])).dataSync();
    selectedAction = ["UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", "RIGHT"][tf.argMax(actionProbs).dataSync()[0]];
  }

  if (selectedAction == "UP" && window.inputDirection.x !== 0) {
    window.inputDirection = { x: 0, y: 1 }
  } else if (selectedAction == "DOWN" && window.inputDirection.x !== 0) {
    window.inputDirection = { x: 0, y: -1 }
  } else if (selectedAction == "LEFT" && window.inputDirection.y !== 0) {
    window.inputDirection = { x: -1, y: 0 }
  } else if (selectedAction == "RIGHT" && window.inputDirection.y !== 0) {
    window.inputDirection = { x: 1, y: 0 }
  }
}

export async function updateAIModel(snakeBody, applePosition, reward, done) {
  const nextState = getState(snakeBody, applePosition);
  let target = reward;
  if (!done) {
    // Predict the future discounted reward
    const futureReward = tf.max(window.model.predict(tf.tensor2d([window.state]))).dataSync()[0];
    target = reward + window.gamma * futureReward;
  }
  // Update the model
  const targetVec = window.model.predict(tf.tensor2d([window.state])).dataSync();
  targetVec[["UP", "DOWN", "LEFT", "RIGHT"].indexOf(window.inputDirection)] = target;
  await window.model.fit(tf.tensor2d([window.state]), tf.tensor2d([targetVec]));
  if (!done) {
    window.state = nextState;
  }
  window.epsilon *= 0.995;
}
```

Comment: It seems that front-end project. why don't you share your code with sandbox platforms like codesandbox.io? It would be very helpful for everyone to trace your problems.

Comment: Alright I made a sandbox project, however here I get an error that I dont get normally, I think its a weird problem with tensorflow and sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-mccarthy-fnstfz?file=/artificialIntelligence.js

Answer (score 0):

You aren't updating which grid space it can go to, you're updating which direction it turns. This makes it spin in circles instead of checking different places for the apple.